# Azure function returns 404

Tags: azure-functions

[image]

I has such function but when build it then shows no function found, and use postman to call it (via url http://localhost:7071/api/SubmitFeedback with POST body) returns 404..

Comment: What is the SDK version? You can run func in diagnostic mode and check the logs why functions are not found? Also, do you see the similar behavior when create a new project?

Comment: Is the request method switched to [post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyP6O.png)?

Comment: Thanks, I know the cause, because the file "local.settings.json" is inside the .gitignore by default, and I clone the code from repo but didn't noticed the file is missing, copy the file into the folder will be fine.

Comment: Maybe you can post an answer to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments mentioned, the error is caused by missing `local.settings.json` file, just add the correct `local.settings.json` to solve the problem.